# Terminal closes after idle

Tags: terminal

I have several CentOS 8.1 boxes with this issue.  When a user leaves a terminal open and leaves for a bit, the screen locks, when they come back the terminal window is gone.  We've set the "leave open" when script completes in preferences but it still closes.  I've fixed it before but can't remember what I did.  I think it was a reinstall of an admin pack but not sure.

Comment: `echo $TMOUT` - check what the shell timeout setting is ?

Comment: Nearly a month later I got around to checking.  When I run echo $TMOUT I get a blank line.